# Проблемы при работе с excel-файлом нового формата в java, android

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

Хотел создать приложение на android, с помощью которого можно считать некоторые данные из excel-файла на sd-карте, но столкнулся с проблемой. Нужный файл сохранён в новом формате xlsx. С одной стороны, jexcelapi не позволяет работать с таким форматом, эта библиотека работает только с xls. Пересохранение исходного файла в формат xls не даёт результата: при попытке обратиться ко второму листу документа, или к какой-то конкретной ячейке выбрасывается исключение ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. С другой стороны, apache-poi тоже не работает на android с форматом xlsx, выбрасываются исключения при попытке открыть файл. (Вроде это из-за ограничений самой платформы android).
Можно ли вообще как-то прочитать данные файла или изменить его так, чтобы он читался?
Вот метод, с помощью которого происходит считывание информации:

```
public String readExcelFile(String name){
    try{
        File file = new File(name);
        Workbook mWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
        Sheet sheet = mWorkbook.getSheet(1); // выбрасывается исключение ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, хотя метод getNumberOfSheets() возвращает правильное число листов.
        return sheet.getName();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("IOE", "IOException");
        return "IOE";
    }catch (BiffException bf){
        bf.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Biff", "BiffException");
        return "Biff";
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ar){
        ar.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Array", "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");
        return "ArrayIOB";
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы пробовали искать решение в интернете? Я только что попробовал, и нашел решение примерно за 24 секунды.

Comment: http://www.java67.com/2014/09/how-to-read-write-xlsx-file-in-java-apache-poi-example.html  прошу ознакомиться сначала с этим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>




public static void readFromExcel(String file) throws IOException{
        HSSFWorkbook myExcelBook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
        HSSFSheet myExcelSheet = myExcelBook.getSheet("Birthdays");
        HSSFRow row = myExcelSheet.getRow(0);

        if(row.getCell(0).getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
            String name = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            System.out.println("name : " + name);
        }

        if(row.getCell(1).getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
            Date birthdate = row.getCell(1).getDateCellValue();
            System.out.println("birthdate :" + birthdate);
        }

        myExcelBook.close();

    }
```

другой пример

```
 File excel = new File("C://temp/Employee.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);

        Iterator<Row> itr = sheet.iterator();

        // Iterating over Excel file in Java
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Row row = itr.next();

            // Iterating over each column of Excel file
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t");
                    break;
                default:

                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

чтение из `xlsx` файлов ничем принципиально не отличается — нужно только вместо `HSSFWorkBook`, `HSSFSheet`, `HSSFRow` (и прочих) из `poi-XX.jar` использовать `XSSFWorkBook`, `XSSFSheet`, `XSSFRow` из `poi-ooxml-XX.jar`.